# How to Edit Data fetched from DB in Python Flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am encountering issue in editing the values fetched from DB. 
Encountering the below error:

> mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError:  (1064, "You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual  that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the  right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1")

Results are displayed as below

[image: Display Results]

When Edit Profile is clicked for example the first one the below details are fetched correctly

[image: Web Form GUI]

when editing the details and clicking on Submit encountering the above mentioned error.

Using the below code to edit the results

```
@app.route('/Update', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Update():
        CR_ID = request.args.get('CR_ID')
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        result = cur.execute("""SELECT CR_ID, name, email, CRType from users where CR_ID = %s""",CR_ID)
     #   result = cur.execute("Update table users set name=?, email=?, CRType=? where CR_ID = %s", CR_ID)
        RV = cur.fetchall()
        user = RV[0]
        cur.close()
        return render_template('Update.html',user=user)
```

to Update the records using the below code:

```
@app.route('/UpdateData', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def UpdateData():
        name = request.args.get('name')
        email = request.args.get('email')
        CRType = request.args.get('CRType')
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        result = cur.execute("""Update table users set name=?, email=?, CRType=? where CR_ID = ?""")
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        return index()
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. The `/Update` route isn't really "editing" anything. I only see a `SELECT` query. It is not clear exactly which snippet of code is causing the error. Is it `/UpdateData`?

Comment: You do not pass parameters into your `execute` call and MySQL placeholders use `%s`.

Comment: Hi User8212173, Yes you are right. Sorry the names are bit confusing... The /Update only displays the data for editing and actual update takes place in /UpdateData. When updating the data and clicking on Submit .. encountering the mentioned error. Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: Request help to solve this issue